# Migration from xproj to csproj using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

There are a few packages that I am using in my project that are not .NET core compatible. But I had added

```
"frameworks": {
    "net461": {
    }
  }
```

in the project.json after I list my packages to make sure the packages are compatible.

With the upgrade in VS2017 to .csproj, and according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj) I replaced the above with

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I still am not able to work with those packages and no MS docs talk about it.
Please pitch in with your response. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Your initial project was built with .net 4.6.1 that has more packages then .net core 1.0.

In order to migrate to VS2017 you can replace the

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
```

with

`<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>`

an then it should work